# Eclipse / Subversion: How to revert ignoring files

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

In my Eclipse/ SVN Project (at Windows envoiriment), the `*.jasper` files are igonored. I want to add them to control version. However it has not been easy.

- If I try to right click in a jasper file and select "Version" -> "Add
  to Control version" or "Commit", this selected file is not showed in dialog.
- I went to "Preferences" -> "Team" -> "Ignored Resources" and remove
  the reference to jasper files. However, the situation above reamins.
- I have neither SVN command-line client nor TortoiseSVN. Also, I'm not authorized to install them. Therefore, I cannot use command line (such as `svn propset svn:ignore "*.jasper"`) and my only option is use Eclipse.

So my question is: How to force my Eclipse "unignore" an ignored file or a group of files without useing the command-line client?

Answer (score 0):

Open window/preferences panel and expand to Team option, then go to ingnored resources and uncheck the incorrect extensions.

Comment: It will unignore files matching `*.jasper` pattern for everyone.

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work. Both "Add to Control Version" and "commit" continue to ignore jasper files. Even after I uncheck jasper in ingnored resources.

Comment: maybe eclipse (or scm plugin) is ignoring files that are generated after a build process [link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/802301/jasper-file-ignored-svn)

Answer (score 0):

remve property svn:ignore frome parent folders of *.jasper files. On a folder right click > team > show properties > [select property] > right click on it > delete property. this is the case in subclipse. maybe similar in subversive

---

it seems eclipse (or scm plugin) is ignoring files that are generated after a build process. [about](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/802301/jasper-file-ignored-svn)

Comment: It's the same in `subversive`. You can remove or edit the svn:ignore property.

Comment: @guleryuz: When I tried to make right click on jasper folder> team > show properties, there was no properties to be selected.

Comment: @Tobias How can I do it, throught Eclipse? Remember that I cannot use command line.

Comment: you should look the very first parent folder of XXX.jasper files

Comment: @RafaelAfonso, I've tested as guleryuz says. "Right click -> team -> show properties" and I can see and edit svn:ignore (if the folder has this property set). Maybe you should check all parent folders. I'm using svn connector for versión 1.6